# how to make two chunks of a string having characters too using c#

Tags: c#, split

```
4200 47 Street Alberta Beach, T0E 0A0 AB 780-544-0137
```

this is my string having character values as well, the last characters having - in them is a phone number i want to make two chunks so i can save phone number in different and the first alphanumeric thing in a different variable using c#. can anyone help me how to do this?
i have used regex for number and for string like

```
PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(Addrs, "[^000-9--]+", string.Empty);
```

and for string i have used regex as well

```
Address = Regex.Replace(Addrs, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

but
the problem is , the address contains characters as well and this regex will split only character into one and string into one chunk

Comment: Should we *help* you or *write the code for you*? We won´t do the latter, you have to show some own affords.

Comment: 'String.Split(',')`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere what should i do now?

Comment: What is the problem with this? It´s absolutely unclear what youßre asking and what you´ve already tried.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i want to store phone number in another variable and string(which may contain characters as well) in another variable but the thing i have tried yet i updated in my question. when it will make two chunks the first characters of address will come in my phone number as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Use something like http://regexr.com/ to experiment.

Assuming the phone number is always as in the example provided and at the end of the string,

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

- \d{3} = exactly 3 digits
- followed by dash
- \d{3} = exactly 3 digits
- followed by dash
- \d{4} = exactly 4 digits
- $ = end anchor

  ```
  string text = "4200 47 Street Alberta Beach, T0E 0A0 AB 780-544-0137";
  string pattern = @"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$"; 
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  Match match = rgx.Match (text);
  if (match.Success) {
      string phoneNumber = match.Value;
      Console.WriteLine (phoneNumber); //780-544-0137

      string rest = text.Substring(0,text.Length-phoneNumber.Length);
      Console.WriteLine (rest);
  }
  ```

Comment: yes the phone number will always be at the end of the string @robor78

Comment: Thanks i am gonna try that

Comment: this way i am saving my phone number but how will i save the rest of the alphanumeric part in another variable???

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's a bit of a hack. One would need to know more about the input string.